# Measurability of a Bochner measurable $L^p$-valued function

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, measurable-functions, bochner-spaces

Currently, I am reading "Interpolation Theory" (3rd edition) by Alessandra Lunardi. In Example 1.15, the following is claimed:
A function
$$
w \colon (0,\infty) \to L^p(\mathbb R^n)
$$
is Bochner measurable if and only if the function
$$
w_{t,x} \colon (0, \infty) \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R, (t,x) \mapsto w(t)(x)
$$
is measurable.

So far, I have achieved to prove the direction "$\Leftarrow$".
However, I don't get the other direction working. Here is the best I have done so far:
Since $w$ is Bochner measurable, there is a sequence of simple functions converging point-wisely to $w$, i.e. there are disjoint Borel measurable sets $A_{i,n}$ and $a_{i,n} \in L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ such that for
$$
f_n = \sum_{i=1}^{m_n} a_{i,n} \chi_{A_{i,n}}
$$
we have that $f_n(t) \to w(t)$ in $L^p(\mathbb R ^n)$ for every $t > 0$. In order to get measurability of $w_{t,x}$ I would hope for the point-wise convergence of $f_n(t)(\cdot) \to w(t)(\cdot)$, however I have no idea how to achieve this for all $t$ simultaneously (since there are uncountable many $t$ a diagonal sequence argument does not seem to work).

Any kind of help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: $w(t)(x)$ isn't even well defined since you can't evaluate functions in $L^p$ on a set of measure $0$.

Comment: You are right, howewver, this is how the author of the book wrote it.  I think, it is meant in the sense that, for each $t$, you pick a representative of the $L^p$-function $w(t)$ and define $w_{t,x}$ using the chosen representatives. The claim would be that then there is a choice of representatives such that $w_{t,x} is measurable.

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184748/if-fx-bullet-in-l2g-b-for-all-x-in-g-then-is-x-mapsto-f?noredirect=1&lq=1) thread maybe useful.